# How do I get a Facebook user’s profile picture URL by user profile link?

Tags: php, facebook, user-profile

I know that there is a logic to create a link to user profile image by using the user id. But I only have the link to the Facebook user profile not the Facebook user id.

I think maybe there need to be done getting the userid first and after that to create a link to user profile image by using that link logic.

i.e.
function getUserProfileImageURI(profileUri){
...
return FBUserProfileimgurl;
}

Comment: There is no way any more, to get the user id from the username, via the API. What you want can not be done using any official, allowed way.